# Unable to retrieve values from jquery generated object

Tags: jquery, object

I'm using 'async' functions and 'let' for the first time, in order to get a list of suppliers which made sales (totalGBP) along with eventually a list of other key metrics:

prior to using async I've never understood promises, deferred etc. I think I'm using them correctly. Without them the $.each would

```
getRetentionData();

async function getRetentionData() {
    try {
        //first function to get supplier names
        let suppliers = await GetSuppliers();
        //console.log(suppliers, suppliers[0].supplier);
        
        $.each(suppliers, function (index, value) {
            console.log("This output correctly");
        });

        //second function to make new array with suppliers metrics
        let stuff = await GetRetentionValues(suppliers); 
        
        $.each(stuff, function (index, value) {
            console.log("This doesn't output & no errors");
        });

        //pass stuff values to DOM
    }
};

function GetSuppliers() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { POSTsuppliers: true },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}


async function GetRetentionValues(suppliers) {
    
    let suppliersRetention = [];
    let i = 0;

    $.each(suppliers, async function (index, line) {
        
        let list = await LowStockProducts(suppliers[index].supplier, 3);
    
        let totalGBP = 0;
        $.each(list, function (index, line) {
            totalGBP = parseFloat(totalGBP + (line.a * line.b));
        });
        
        //add suppliers to new array GBP above 0
        if (totalGBP > 0) {
            suppliersRetention[i] = { 
                supplier: suppliers[index].supplier,
                ttlGBP: totalGBP,
                allOrdersGBP: allOrdersGBP
            };
            i = i + 1;
        };
    
    });

    console.log(suppliersRetention);
    return suppliersRetention;
        
}
```

Console.log(suppliers, suppliers[0].supplier); outputs:

```
(8) […]
0: Object { supplier: "supplier1" }
1: Object { supplier: "supplier2" }
2: Object { supplier: "supplier3" }...
supplier1
```

When I create a new array called suppliersRetention to include other values, I can view the array output:
console.log(suppliersRetention);

```
[]
0: Object { supplier: "supplier1", ttlGBP: 213.9 }
1: Object { supplier: "supplier2", ttlGBP: 14 }
2: Object { supplier: "supplier3", ttlGBP: 152 }
```

However I'm unable to get the values out of suppliersRetention using suppliersRetention[0].totalGBP

```
TypeError: "suppliersRetention[0] is undefined"
```

If I manually create the array I can

```
suppliersRetention = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    
    suppliersRetention[i] = {
        supplier: "supplier1",
        totalGBP: 100
    }
}
console.log( suppliersRetention[0].totalGBP );
OUTPUT: 100
```

I can only assume there is a problem with my array. I've tried with objects and arrays with the same undefined TypeError

Comment: We need to see the higher level code context of these ajax calls. Sounds like `suppliers` is either undefined or empty array at the time you use that `$.each`. That `async` in the `each` callback will not work as you expect either. Hard to pinpoint where the issue is without seeing more of the code structure

Comment: Thank you. I've added more context. Hopefully not too much.

Comment: Strongly suggest learning how to use promises correctly then start using `async/await`. The `each` loop will not break for the `await` for example. *"I think I'm using them properly"* therefore is a bad assumption. `async/await` does not make all asynchronous operations synchronous. That is a really important concept to understand. Will add some better approaches using straight promises in an answer

Comment: Hello charlietfl, did you manage to find a moment to identify where the problem is? Do you believe it's the array or the async/await timing? Thank you

Comment: Suggest you map array of promises and use `Promise.all()` rather than using `$.each`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll look into Promise.all() now.